# Graphical Representation of Derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We know that the derivative function takes as its input a function and gives out another one. The output function is the rate of change of the input function wrt the independent variable which changes by an infinitesimal amount. As an intuition the derivative at a point is Graphically represented as a tangent. 
1) If that is so then why is the output function not always in the form of y=mx+c ?
If we plug in the value of x in the  first order derivative we get another value for y, which represents a point. How is a tangent related to this?
2) Moreover how do the higher order derivatives look graphically ?
3) How can some functions have the rate of growth equal to themselves?

Comment: Wrong side of *StackExchange*

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Answer (score 2):

Re. 1) ... why is the output function not always in the form of y = mx+c ?

The output (derivative) is the `m` term of the tangent `m x + c`.

Demonstrating with an example using the function `y = 2 x^3 + 60`

```
f[x_] := 2 x^3 + 60
```

For `x = 4`

```
y = f[4]
```

> 188

Curve of `y = 2x^3 + 60` with a line at `x = 4`

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 5},
 Epilog -> Line[{{4, 0}, {4, 300}}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

A small change `Δx` to the input function produces a small change in the output.

```
Δy = (2 (x + Δx)^3 + 60) - (2 x^3 + 60)
```

> -2 x^3 + 2 (x + Δx)^3

$\frac{\text{$\Delta $y}}{\text{$\Delta $x}}=\frac{-2 x^3+2 (x+\text{$\Delta $x})^3}{\text{$\Delta $x}}$

```
Expand[(-2 x^3 + 2 (x + Δx)^3)/Δx]
```

> 6 x^2 + 6 x Δx + 2 Δx^2

The derivative `6 x^2` is approached as `Δx` tends to zero.

Also via Mathematica

```
slope = m = D[f[x], x]
```

> 6 x^2

For `x = 4`

```
x = 4;

Solve[f[x] == m x + c, c]
```

> {{c -> -196}}

```
c = -196;
m = 6 x^2
```

> 96

```
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 5},
  Epilog -> Line[{{4, 0}, {4, 300}}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
 Plot[m x + c, {x, -3, 5}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 2]]]
```

[image]

Re. 3) How can some functions have the rate of growth equal to themselves?

$n e^x$ is the *only* function with a rate of growth equal to itself.

```
g[x_] := n E^x

slope = m = D[g[x], x]
```

> E^x n

The reason for this can be illustrated by noting the series that represents $e^x$.

Taking just the first 10 terms of this infinite series.

```
s = Normal[Series[E^x, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

$1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{x^7}{5040}+\frac{x^8}{40320}+\frac{x^9}{362880}+\frac{x^{10}}{3628800}$

```
ds = D[s, x]
```

$1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{x^7}{5040}+\frac{x^8}{40320}+\frac{x^9}{362880}$

For `x = 4`

```
x = 4;

N[s]
```

> 54.4431

```
N[ds]
```

> 54.1541

If this calculation is done using the full infinite series the results are equal.